# The task is to convert a decimal number into its binary form. For example if I input 9 it should result 1001

Tags: c++, loops

This is the code I came up with, here we use the remainder method to find the binary representation of a number.
There are basically two problems:

1. If the number is large say 1111111 then it is outputting 1.11111e+6
2. I am not getting the decimal part for every number and for some small numbers the decimal part doesn't go further than two decimal points. Eg: Input 9.3 ----> Output 1001.01

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  float n,a = 0; int i = 0,j = 0;
  cin >> n;
  int b = n; float x = n-b;
  while(b > 0){ //For the integer part of the number
    i = b%2;
    b = b/2;
    a = a + pow(10,j)*i;
    j++;
  }
  //I chose 8 because I want presicion to be upto 8 digits
  float k = 0; int m = 1;
  while(m <= 8){ //For the decimal part of the number
    x = x*2.0;
    int y = x; 
    k = k + y/(pow(10,m));
    m++;
    x = x - y;
  }
  cout << a + k << "\n";
}
```

There are basically two problems:

1. If the number is large say 1111111 then it is outputting 1.11111e+6
2. I am not getting the decimal part for every number and for some small numbers the decimal part doesn't go further than two decimal points. Eg: Input 9.3 ----> Output 1001.01
   In the first one I was expecting the entire number to be printed instead of e+6 and in the second part it should have at least printed till 8 digits after decimal.
3. When I input 53.67, only the integer part gets printed

Comment: Don't use floating-point types and functions for integer values.

Comment: Conversion from decimal to binary doesn't generally take a floating point value, and produce another floating point value (i.e.  `float` with value `9` becomes `float` with `1001`).     Even from yout example, it's possible to see that the "converted" value will be much larger than the input value - a 7-digit decimal value will have (at least) 20 binary digits, and storing it the way you are in a float produces values that quite quickly exceed what a `float` (or even a `double`) can represent.  That's why the usual way to do such a "conversion" is to produce a *string*.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Please hard-code the value that causes problems. Also, restrict this question to one problem, not two/three. BTW: Cramming multiple declarations into one line doesn't help in readability. Also, single-letter identifiers are not helpful. The conversion could also be put into a function, to separate it from the input and output.

Comment: "Converting" nine to one thousand and one is not a decimal-to-binary conversion.

Comment: You might want to print an integer in binary (or you might want to print it in decimal) but integers are just integers they don't have a base. What you are doing is transforming an integer so that if it is printed as decimal it looks like the original integer printed in binary. That's a pretty twisted thing to do. I suggest that you instead think about how to **print** an integer in a binary form without doing any tranformation of the value.

Comment: I recommend to put your output into a string instead of an integer number.  The string can accommodate more digits.  You could also use a `std::stack<char>` so that the order of the bits will be correct order when you pop everything off the stack.

Comment: As usual in these questions, there is no decimal to binary conversion in your code. Decimal to *floating-point* conversion happens at `cin >> n`. The rest just converts to printable binary.

Answer (score 0):

- `float` and `double` calculations are in base 2, and your input is in base 10, so you are losing precision when converting it, read your input into std::string. find the decimal point and separate it into two `int`s. the left of the decimal point is the integer part, and the right side is the fraction.
- the result is also a string in a manner to avoid integer's overflow or exponent value (like: 1.11111e+6).
- on the integer part you can use the unary and operator (`&`) to check if a bit is on or off, then add '1' or '0' to the result string, then you can use the shift right operator (`>>`) to divide by 2 and get rid of the bit you already found.
- on the fraction part you can check how many digits you have. then create a "logical half" by using the same length number starting with 5 with the following zeros. if you have 1 digit after the decimal point, use 5 if you have 2 digits use 50, for three use 500, and so on... if your fraction is larger than or equal to the "logic half" you append '1' and subtract the logic half from the number, otherwise you just append '0' without the subtraction, then you need to multiply the number by 2 or use the shift left operator (`<<`) you can do it 8 times for 8 decimal point digits or until the fraction is zero. (a similar calculation can be with a logical one, but then you first multiply by 2 and then check if it is greater than the logical 1)

Here is an example, but without error detection. (like input error...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    std::string number, result, part1, part2;
    int integer=0, fraction=0, half=5, decimal_digits = 8;
    cin >> number;
    
    size_t decimal_point = number.find_first_of(".");
    if (decimal_point > 0) 
    {
        part1 = number.substr(0, decimal_point);
        integer = std::atoi(part1.c_str());
    }
    if (decimal_point != number.npos)
    {
        part2 = number.substr(decimal_point + 1);
        fraction = std::atoi(part2.c_str());
    }
    while (integer > 0)
    {
        result = std::string((integer & 1) ? "1" : "0") + result;
        integer >>= 1; // /=2
    }
    if (fraction)
    {
        result += ".";
    }
    for (size_t i = part2.size(); i>1; i--)
    {
        half *= 10;
    }
    while (fraction && decimal_digits--)
    {
        if (fraction >= half)
        {
            result += "1";
            fraction -= half;
        }
        else
        {
            result += "0";
        }
        fraction <<= 1; // *=2
    }
    if (fraction)
    {
        result += "...";
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```